# Jenkins Windows Master to connect to Slave Mac OSX

Tags: windows, macos, ssh, jenkins, hudson

I have Jenkins set up on both my Windows7 PC and a Mac mini in order to build the various platforms (Blackberry, Android and iOS projects)

Problem I've encounered is the Win7 Master jenkins can't seem to connect to the mac slaves.  I've tried opening up port 22 on the firewall so don't think it's this (although not 100% certain) and doing some reading on it all the tutorials mention about setting up SSH public keys but they all refer to mac and linux rather than Win7 as this doesn't appear to be a valid approach from what I understand.

Has anyone done this and/or got any pointers as to why Win7 can't seem to see the mac?  (I can ping it if that helps reassure they're on the same network)

Here's the console output should it be of any use.

```
    [10/04/12 23:10:35] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 192.168.0.102:22.
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to 192.168.0.102:22
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:793)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:565)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:650)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.launch(SSHLauncher.java:283)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.establishConnection(TransportManager.java:346)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.initialize(TransportManager.java:454)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:733)
    ... 9 more
[10/04/12 23:10:56] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Comment: What option do you have selected for your slaves in the "Launch Method" field of the slave setup ?

Comment: I might be getting in a muddle here.  So I've tried using the 'Launch slave agents on unix machines using ssh' as I thought this would be the right way to do it.  I've now tried swapping it to 'Java web start' and can get the OSX as master to see the PC as a slave but the error still appears on the set up "Win7 Master-> OSX slave" with the error (Couldn't connect when launching the helper).

Comment: Hmm - it does look from your error message as if you can't get to port 22 on the OSX slave from the Windows machine.  What happens if you try "telnet [OSX slave name or IP address] 22" from the Windows box ?  If you can post the error from the Jenkins log when you try the Java web start method, that would also be useful.

Comment: Can you install Cygwin and try to ssh through it? Also, and I know this sounds like a stupid question, but is the SSH daemon running on your Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH method requires that an SSH server is running on the target that you try to connect to.

Maybe your Mac does not have SSH server running and/or configured.

Answer (score 3):

Configure SSH in your MAC:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

Configure SSH in your Jenkins slave configuration given the location for the ssh private key (slave path).

More details in my [Blog](http://mobiledevtest.blogspot.co.il/2014/01/jenkins-slave-on-mac-or-windows-8.html)